# Microsoft Azure GraphApi fails with invalid JWT token

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, command-line-interface, microsoft-entra-id

When trying to use the Microsoft Azure Graph Api to run cli command the connection call fails with a not very helpful message of invalid JWT token

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.ReadWrite.All", "User.ReadWrite.All", "Domain.ReadWrite.All"
Connect-MgGraph: Invalid JWT access token.

Answer (score 0):

This call seems to work if the user is part of the tenant (*.onmicrosoft.com) or another domain that is registered with the tenant.

The identity that was being used was a MicorosftAccount via invitation. Because of this the call to `Connect-MgGraph` requires passing an additional parameter with tenantid which make some sense because it cant determine to which tenant the operations will be against

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.ReadWrite.All", "User.ReadWrite.All", "Domain.ReadWrite.All" -tenantid xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx
Welcome to Microsoft Graph!
```

Hopefully, someone else can elaborate on my answer. I was able to figure this out after several searches and thanks to this medium article
https://medium.com/@chan.huanjun_94878/fun-with-badzure-setting-up-the-environment-286577c759e0